# Select2 with ajax option

Tags: ajax, jquery-select2

I have been using selec2 version 4 with ajax option.
And I want to set a selected value, as recommended in the guideline, by adding new Option element.

A problem I have is that I do not know when to add the new option because the event select2-loaded does not seem to exist in the latest version of select 2.

Can you please let me know in what way I can know the moment when data has finished loading from the server and has finished setting up, so I can add a new option to it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Option element you mention is created by calling the [Option() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) which then constructs a [HTMLOptionElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement). So basically you are just adding to your DOM and don't need to do it in any select2 event. Instead just do it on document load.

Here's a very basic example of what it could look like:

```
$(function () {
    $('#element-to-select').select2();

    var option = new Option('text', 'value', true, true);
    $('#element-to-select').append(option).trigger('change');
}
```

Note that we are calling `.trigger('change')` to report the change to select2 as documented [here](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#selecting-options).